# Cannot get the right average value of a couple of numbers

Tags: ios, swift

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
var sum = 0
var i = 1
for number in numbers {
    sum += number
    i++
}
return Float(sum)/Float(i)
}

averageOf(1,2,3,4,4)
```

return value

```
2.33333325386047
```

Im new to Swift and run this code in the playground. The return value is not right, but I cannot find where is wrong, since the sum is 14 and the i is 5.

Comment: Think about what you're initializing your `i` variable to. Are you sure you want it to be 1?

Comment: ^ this you should be initializing to 0..
14/6 = 2.3333 that is your problem

Comment: Just stepping through the code in the debugger and watching the values would allow you to find the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with i=0 instead of one. Since you're incrementing i after each number, i is ending up as 6 in your example instead of 5.